# ODE how to specify initial / limiting conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

Please let me explain this situation, I have a ditch which is being filled with rain, the ditch is emptied and can also act as storage if inflow>outflow.

**Q_in-Q_uit=∂V/∂t**

**Q_in**=A*I/1000=[m^3/h], with A area where rain falls, I intensity

**Q_out** = k_strickler*A_cross*R^(2/3)*i^(1/2),
With

R  = hydraulic radius = A_cross/ Perimeter

A_cross = cross section of the ditch = (0.5*B1*H)+(B2*H)+(0.5*B3*H)

Perimeter = √(H^2+B1^2)+B2+√(H^2+B3^2)

[See cross section here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGoUH.png)
With B1 = 1.25 m, B2 = 0.1, B3=1.25 (but these can be tweaked and optimised)

i = height difference over the length of the ditch =around 0.2/180 =0.001 [-]

**Now my question is the follwing:** How do i have to solve this, I am doubtfull about the step ∂V/∂t = A_cross * dh/dt. can i do this?

Now how do i want to solve this, i want to know which dimensions i need to have an equilibrium so the ditch does not flow over, But the ditch needs to be as small as possible (Total width between 2-3m and depth 0.5-1 m)

Can I also deduce that if there is a rain intensity of f.e. 40 mm/h = 40 L/m2/h that after how many minutes the ditch is full and starts to flow over.

I hope my question are clear, I am able to use Pyhton (jupyter) to solve this.

Comment: Please use latex for typing in equations. Please also improve your post as it is quite unclear. It is also more suitable for an engineering SE.

Comment: Hii I understand that it is difficult to read, but i is the best i can do, How can i use Latex? 
Also i didn't know abou the engineering SE, i will post it there as well

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: $$ thank you $$